# Custom action doesn't appear

Tags: 2007, development, custom-actions

I have an issue with custom action in SharePoint 2007, basically i have the following custom action declaration:

```
<Elements Id="CF60B88A-783A-44f8-A49D-43659AB51G7E" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="MyAction.GoToGoogle"
  GroupId="ActionsMenu"
  Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
  RegistrationType="List"
  Rights="Read"
  Sequence="0"
  Title="Go to google"
  ControlAssembly="MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd112ea8ee9f48d3"
  ControlClass="MyProject.CustomActions.MyCustomAction">
    <UrlAction Url="http://www.google.be"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

So basically this custom action is bind to a custom class, but as i said already my action doesn't appear at all, if i delete the control class and control assambly then it is wel visible.

Maybe my delcaration is wrong? Anyone can point me to a mistake?

UPDATE:

Here is the class

```
namespace MyProject.CustomAction
{
    public class MyCustomAction : WebControl
    {
      protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
         }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: without code or error am afraid if anyone would know whats wrong with your custom class, try ULS viewer to find out error, here's a guide http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-use-uls-viewer-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: updated post with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found, basically everything was ok, the problem was due to not registering the class as a safe control, after doing it, the custom action worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Change your `elements.xml` to this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Control
    ControlAssembly="MyProject.CustomAction, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd112ea8ee9f48d3"
    ControlClass="MyProject.CustomActions.MyCustomAction" 
    Sequence="1"
    Id="AdditionalPageHead"/>

  <CustomAction
      Id="MyActionGoToGoogle"
      Title="Go To Google"
      Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
      RegistrationId="101"
      RegistrationType="List"
      GroupId="ActionsMenu"
      ShowInLists="TRUE"
      Sequence="1"
      ControlAssembly="MyProject.CustomAction, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd112ea8ee9f48d3"
      ControlClass="MyProject.CustomActions.MyCustomAction" >
    <UrlAction Url="http://www.google.be"/>
  </CustomAction>

</Elements>
```

and your custom class should look like this,

```
namespace MyProject.CustomAction
{
    public class MyCustomAction : WebControl
    {
      protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            base.OnLoad(e);
         }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nope doesn't work :(

Comment: did you tried ULS viewer to find out whats the error

Comment: i don't see any records about this, i think that nothing is being loaded properly.